# iOS 4 blocks and retain counts

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ios4, retain, objective-c-blocks

I'm just getting started with blocks and Grand Central Dispatch. I've been told (and read in the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html)) that any object referenced from within a block gets retained.

For instance:

```
^{  
    self.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, 0), 1, 1, 1);
    self.layer.opacity = 1;
}
```

"self" gets retained so it leaks. To avoid that, I need to assign self to:

```
__block Object *blockSelf = self;
```

and then use `blockSelf` instead of `self` inside my block.

My question is: what happens when your block has a lot more code and references several objects? Do I need to assign them all to `__block` objects? For instance:

```
^{  
    [self doSomething];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"prevName == %@", artistName];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    Object *newObject = [[Object alloc] init];
    [someArray addObject];
    [newObject release];
}
```

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352561/retain-cycle-on-self-with-blocks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No. The problem occurs when your block retains an object which retains it. Your block will retain any object that it references, except for those annotated with `__block`. Hence:

```
// The following creates a retain cycle which will leak `self`:
self.block = ^{
  [self something];
};
```

`self` retains `block`, and `block` implicitly retains `self`. This will also
happen if you reference instance variables of `self`.

```
// The following avoids this retain cycle:
__block typeof(self) bself = self;
self.block = ^{
  [bself something];
};
```

Variables annotated with `__block` are mutable (for pointers, that is, the
address they point to can be changed); as a result, it makes no sense to
retain that object, since you need to treat that object as a local variable
(as in, it can be reassigned, affecting an object outside the scope of the block). Thus, `__block` don't get retained by blocks.

But, now you can run into unforeseen problems if you try to use this block in certain ways. For instance, if you decide to delay the invocation of this block somehow, and `self` has been deallocated by the time you execute that block, your program will crash, since you're sending a message to a deallocated object. What you need then is a weak reference, which is not provided out-of-the-box in the non-garbage-collected environment!

One solution is to use [MAZeroingWeakRef](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/introducing-mazeroingweakref.html) to wrap your block; this will zero out the pointer so that you'll just end up sending messages to `nil` should you attempt to message `self` after `self` has been deallocated:

```
MAZeroingWeakRef *ref = [MAZeroingWeakRef refWithTarget:self];
self.block = ^{
  [ref.target something];
};
```

I've also implemented a [weak reference wrapper in Objective-C++](https://github.com/jonsterling/SmartObjects/blob/master/ref.hpp), which provides the benefit of a more lightweight syntax:

```
js::weak_ref<SomeClass> ref = self;
self.block = ^{
  [ref something];
};
```

Because `js::weak_ref` is a class template, you'll get handy strong-typing (that is, you'll get warnings at compile-time if you try to send the reference a message which it doesn't appear to respond to). But Mike's `MAZeroingWeakReference` is a lot more mature than mine, so I'd suggest using his unless you want to get your hands dirty.

To read more about issues with `__block` and the use-case for weak references, read [Avoiding retain cycles with blocks, a right way](http://castirony.com/post/3936227677/block-retain-cycle) and [Jonathan Rentzsch's response](http://castirony.com/post/3936227677/block-retain-cycle).

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer Jonathan. So if I'm understanding correctly, I don't even need to assign self to a __block variable as long as I'm not retaining the block for reuse?

Comment: Yep (though I usually do just to be safe). So long as you use the block right then and there and don't copy it, you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Do you mind explaining this a bit more. If you look at this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1 in the Objective-C blocks section, it kinda points otherwise, unless I have read it wrong. I assume he is doing an animation which is used by a class method which, in results, do not retain the block by self hence making it safe. If he'd use any other  implementation where he'd retain partially that block it would leak.

Comment: @Pier-Olivier, I don't quite follow you. Not sure where animation comes into this. However, the rules for blocks are simple: 1. referenced variables not marked `__block` are `const`-copied (for objects, this means a copy of the pointer is made, not a copy of the object); 2. referenced objects not marked `__weak` or `__block` are retained.

Comment: Just remember: arc => `__weak` else => `__block`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it depends what you're doing with your block. If you're not storing it anywhere and use it in the definition place (like sorting an array using a block), then it gets released along with variables referenced inside it (since it's created in stack and is marked for autorelease). If you're storing it somewhere (an array, dictionary or probably pass the block to some other function) `copy` the block and balance it out with `autorelease` before passing it along.