# how to fire block event in objective c when uiviewcontroller dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

How to fire block event in Objective C when UIViewController dealloc.

For example :

```
   [PGMemberObj requestWithUserName:@"ab" andPassword:@"cc" andCallback:^(BOOL isSuc){
        if (isSuc) {
            NSLog("Login Suc.");
        }else
        {
            NSLog("Login Failed");
        }
    }];
```

when i pop ViewController and dealloc was executed,i still receive Login Suc. or Login Failed Message.
How to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
__weak UIViewController *weakSelf = self;
[PGMemberObj requestWithUserName:@"ab" andPassword:@"cc" andCallback:^(BOOL isSuc){
    if ([weakSelf isViewLoaded] && [weakSelf.view window]) 
        //The view controller still exists AND it's being shown on screen
    else
        //Either dealloc'd or not on screen anymore
 }];
```

It will test whether your view controller still exists AND is still on screen.
Just check for `weakSelf` if you don't care if it's still being shown on screen.

```
if (weakSelf)
    //Still exists
else
    //dealloc'd
```

Comment: What happens if weakSelf is already deallocated? Will you not get a BAD_ACCESS trying to send message "isViewLoaded" to already recycled object?

Comment: In case the first won't break at least the second will since testing that weakSelf is not nil will return true if it could respond to isViewLoaded message?

Comment: Well, no, because of && being a lazy operator. That means that if weakSelf is nill, you get that [weakSelf isViewLoaded] is nil, which means that the second part of the guard won't even be evaluated.

Comment: Well if you would first check that weakSelf is not nil and then do && and check id view is loaded i guess it would work if recycled objects are set to nil, and that i am not certain off. [nil isViewLoaded] will defiantly break.

Comment: You should check what happens in Objective-C when you call a method on a nil object :)

Comment: Wow that is actually very scary.. I have called methods on already released objects(i think now..) and they have generated errors. But those times the reference was no nil but of this type __NSCFType. Well anyway then i guess it works!

Comment: "Well if you would first check that weakSelf is not nil" hey guys, I fear that is totally wrong .. the whole point of the __weak is that it retains ("for the block") the self.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you right, you want to stop the block from executing if your view controller is no longer alive? It's a little bit tricky since the block is sent to your PGMemberObj so your view controller no longer has any control over the block code. The cancelling has to be done where your block is executed, in your `PGMemberObj requestWithUserName` method. Maybe you can have a __block variable set to your view controller and check if that has been deallocated before you fire the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution that I can think of would be to cancel the authentication if it's no longer needed. This means that your `PGMemberObj` should contain a `cancel` (or similar) method that would cancel its authentication process.

Another way would be to reset the block to `nil`. In this case, your `PGMemberObj` should have a member object to hold the authentication callback block, along with a `copy` property.

You'd call the `cancel` method, or reset the `block` inside your `dealloc` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your completion block is typically a secondary thread.

You can try something like,

```
  [PGMemberObj requestWithUserName:@"ab" andPassword:@"cc" andCallback:^(BOOL isSuc){
        if (isSuc)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login Suc.");
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        } 
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Login Failed");
            UIAlertView *al=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Invalid username or password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [al show];

        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with something like this:

```
__weak id *myWeakSelf = self;
[PGMemberObj requestWithUserName:@"ab" andPassword:@"cc" andCallback:^(BOOL isSuc) {

    if (!myWeakSelf)
        return;

    if (isSuc) {
        NSLog("Login Suc.");
    }else
    {
        NSLog("Login Failed");
    }
}];
```

Using the `weak` reference to self will allow to detect when the block body is executed after `self` has been deallocated. Indeed, in such case `myWeakSelf` will be found to be `nil` at the start of the block.

If you want to altogether prevent the block from being called, you need to setup some mechanism so that your `PGMemberObj` object does know that the block should not be executed anymore. In this case, again, weak references might come to the rescue and you could set a `weak` property of your `PGMemberObj` so that it will be nil-ed when the requesting object is deallocated (in this case, you will only able to have one outstanding request).

Comment: if (!myWeakSelf)    return; is totallt wrong I fear; .. the whole point is you have retained it!  (With ARC.)  It will never be nil in the block!  it would be like asking if(!self) in the routine itself.  it's impossible for !self to be true!

Comment: @JoeBlow: `__weak` means the reference will be nil-ed when the object that it points to is deallocated. Furthermore, being `weak` it will not be retained through the block. Hence, `myWeakSelf` will be nil in the block after object deallocation.