# Retaining mutable variables in blocks without causing retain cycles in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, retain, block

I'm using blocks to handle the response of async http requests in a non-ARC project. The code looks like this (the relevant parts):

```
NSMutableUrlRequest* request = ...;
__block typeof(self) mutableSelf = self;

void (^didGetSessionBlock)(Gopher* newGopher) = ^(Gopher* newGopher) {
    if (newGopher.statusCode == HTTP_OK) {
        ...
        mutableSelf.retryOnFail = NO;
        [mutableSelf executeRequest:request];
    }

    ...
    [mutableSelf setStatusCode:newGopher.statusCode];
};

Gopher* newGopher = [[[Gopher alloc] init] autorelease];

[newGopher setDidCompleteBlock:didGetSessionBlock];
[newGopher fetchSession:myApp.settings.userName password:myApp.settings.password];
```

`__block mutableSelf` is used so that I can modify `self` inside of the block (and not a copy of `self`). The `__block` keyword, if I understand correctly, also has the effect that `mutableSelf` is not retained so it might already be released when the block is executing (and this is exactly what happens).

If I change

```
[mutableSelf executeRequest:request];
```

to

```
[self executeRequest:request];
```

all is well since `self` gets retained and won't be released until the block has executed. However, directly referencing self might cause leaks due to retain cycles.

Is there a way around this? Should I manually retain `mutableSelf` when it's declared and then release it inside of the block? Or should I use `self` inside the block where I'm not modifying it, potentially creating a leak? Both variants seem fragile and need explanations in comments to avoid confusion and future bugs if/when the code is modified.

Is there a way to solve this problem? If not, what is the best approach?

Comment: You might like to have a look at [Retain cycle on self with Blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352561/retain-cycle-on-self-with-blocks) and its answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't modify `self` in the block, you only modify the object pointed to by it.  I don't think you need `__block`.

Comment: Aha. So `__block` is only necessary when wanting to modify stack variables? Also, how do I get passed the possible retain cycle problem if not using `__block` for `self`?