# UIActivityViewController - can't understand this memory leak

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiactivityviewcontroller

Can someone please tell me why the following code is leaking in Instruments?

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b", nil];


[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
[activityController release];
```

Instruments show the leak on row:

```
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b", nil];
```

Comment: What does the static analyzer say, because I see no leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick (__block and completion)

```
__block UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b", nil];

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:^{ activityController.excludedActivityTypes=nil; activityController=nil;}];
[activityController release];
```

See also this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442910/nsarray-excludedactivities-leaks-memory-even-when-using-arc-and-setting-it-to-n)