# UIActivityViewController leaks / memory issue in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to use UIActivityViewController in MonoTouch. You can see below the code. My issue is that the code is leaking (according to monotouch memory profiler) and using a lot a memory due to an image that is loaded each time we display the view controller. I tried to implement the solution:

[NSArray* excludedActivities Leaks memory even when using ARC and setting it to nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442910/nsarray-excludedactivities-leaks-memory-even-when-using-arc-and-setting-it-to-n)

[How to fix memory leak for UIActivityViewController presented in a UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561289/how-to-fix-memory-leak-for-uiactivityviewcontroller-presented-in-a-uipopovercont?lq=1)

and to dispose the activity view controller and the image in the completion handler, but I have always the same issue. Someone had the same issue and find a solution?

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile("imagePath");

  NSObject[] activityItems = new NSObject[] {
    new NSString("text"),
    image
  };

  UIActivityViewController activityController = new UIActivityViewController(activityItems, null);
  activityController.ExcludedActivityTypes = new NSString[] {UIActivityType.Message};
  activityController.CompletionHandler = (activityType, completed) =>
  {
    activityController.ExcludedActivityTypes = null;
    activityController.Dispose();
    activityController = null;

    image.Dispose(); 
    image = null;
  };
  this.NavigationController.PresentViewController(activityController, true, () => {});
}
```

Comment: This code looks ok - assuming the CompletionHandler is actually called (you can confirm this by putting a breakpoint there and see if it's hit).

Comment: Do you have a complete self contained sample that would replicate the issue?