# Retain cycle with parent-child construction

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, retaincount

Its very common question everybody familiar with, but I'm still not understand it fully.

If Object A owns (have a strong property of) Object B, and Object B have a strong property of object A, there is retain cycle, and no object can be released and there is a memory leak.

But, what if Object A instead will point for Object C instead of Object B, therefore another address in memory?

As far as i know, strong properties do something like follow:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)newObject{
if (_newObject == newObject){
return; //
}

NSObject *oldObject = _newObject;
_newObject = [newObject retain];
[oldObject release];
}
```

So, what if we point instead for Object C, isn't in that case memory for Object B will be released? What if both Objects (A and B) will instead set `nil` object? Is there still would be retain cycle with memory leak? With old value "floating" somewhere in memory?

I know, that has been discussed many times, but i still can't get "whole picture" in my head. I would appreciate any clarification in that matter.

Comment: The allocation instruments has tools to help aid in cycle detection.  I suggest you explore said tools.   If you want to write example code to play with, create your own subclass of `NSObject` so you don't run into static instances (like @"foo") or tagged pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you are looking for is "retain cycle".

The simplest retain cycle would be an object having a strong reference to itself. Very rare because it is rather pointless.

The most common case is A having a strong reference to B and B having a strong reference to A. A->B->A. You see the cycle?

The cycle can be any length A->B->C->D->E->F->G->...->A. It's a retain cycle, so nothing will be released. If you have just A->B->C->D->...->Z with no reference back to another object in the sequence, then there is no cycle. No cycle, no problem.

Comment: so, if we have cycle A>B>A, and then we do A>C and B>D, with same strong reference, there would be no memory leak and therefore retain cycle?

Comment: An object having a strong reference to itself is not rare there days, by the way, since objects in Swift can have closures as their properties, which catch a strong reference to `self` once you access any property or method of `self` inside that closure. Obj-C blocks can also cause retain cycles with `self`, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352561/retain-cycle-on-self-with-blocks?rq=1

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban  Both this answer and JeremyP's answer are correct.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is "can you break a retain cycle by reassigning one of the properties?", the answer is yes.  This applies equally if you assign nil to the property.

Comment: if just one of the properties would be re-assigned - set to nil, it would be enough to get rid of retain cyrcle?

Comment: yes. Because the cycle exists when both refer to each other. So if A -> B but B -> NIL, you have no cycle. But this is all academic, you should be using a strong A-> B and a weak B->A (or assign, but usually weak is appropriate).